# Why does this macro not work like I think it would?

Tags: c, macros, structure, c-preprocessor

I'm a little new to C still, so bear with me.

I am attempting to be able to refer to the elements of a structure via an index. I figured a macro would do the trick, but evidently not. Can anyone explain why the following does not work?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define E(Structure, Index) Structure.var_Index

typedef struct test{
    int var_0;
}TEST;

int main(){
    TEST Test;
    
    E(Test, 0) = 0;
    
    return(0);
}
```

My IDE says "No member named 'var_Index' in 'struct test'," but I have no # in front of the word Index in the macro.

Comment: The Answers below are correct regarding the concatenation pre-processor operator, but to be clear this is all done at compile time and is fixed. The parameter Index in your example must always resolve to the desired suffix at compile time, it can't be a variable.

Comment: Right. I was more looking to simplify some notation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Merging tokens is done with `##`

The following change should work:

```
#define E(Structure, Index) Structure.var_##Index
```

Answer (score 5):

`var_Index` is one token and the compiler (preprocessor) won't see as `Index`.

You can use `##` operator to have it concatenate tokens in macros.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define E(Structure, Index) Structure.var_##Index

typedef struct test{
    int var_0;
}TEST;

int main(){
    TEST Test;
    
    E(Test, 0) = 0;
    
    return(0);
}
```